# jQuery .load fails in IE9, not in Firefox, Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I've got a Wordpress running on cphdans.dk and are using the plugin Code Embed which let you add JavaScript directly to a post.

The JavaScript I'm embedding is:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    jQuery("#loadTilmelding").load("http://pbs.cphdans.dk/index_dansidk.php#body");
});
</script>
```

Things work fine in Safari, Chrome and Firefox - but when trying to view the page in Internet Explorer I get nothing loaded.
The developer tools in IE9 doesn't report any errors in this matter.

I've Googled around and found similar issues when the html wasn't validated with w3, but I've done that with the page I'm trying to load into the DOM:

```
http://pbs.cphdans.dk/index_dansidk.php
```

When trying to output the loaded content into the log in IE I just get:

```
LOG: undefined
```

How can I debug when IE doesn't report any errors, and does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Did you try to clear cache: `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });`?

Comment: I'm running jQuery 1.7.2 as we are using the Cherry framework for Wordpress. Clearing the cache has been trying.